# How to get the value of dynamic column in custom mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've twelve columns for twelve months separately as shown in the image below
[image]
Now, when I change the month, I need to get the specific month value.
I tried to get the column value dynamically as the below query.

```
SET @monthColumnName = LOWER(DATE_FORMAT('2022-10-02', '%b_goal'));
SELECT @monthColumnName FROM goals;
```

but it gives the column name instead of the value as shown below in the image.
[image]

How to get the value of dynamic columns in mysql custom query?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use a properly normalized database format?

Comment: Also, does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949624/mysql-select-query-with-variable-column-name help?

Comment: No, I checked and tried with the above link solution, but it doesn't help me.
Also, I wished for a normalized database format, but this exact format is required according to the client requirements. So I'm trying with it.

Comment: "I've twelve columns for twelve months" Bad idea.  This is the wrong way to design a database schema.

Comment: @DanielFarrell, You are right, but we must need the current format according to the UI and client requirements.  So I'm trying to get a solution for the current DB format.

Comment: i would use an auxiliary table mapping columns with months